# Base85 Encoding

Tags: code-golf, math, string, base-conversion

## The Challenge

Write a program that can take an input of a single-line string containing any ASCII printable characters, and output the same string encoded in [Base85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) (using a big-endian convention). You can assume that the input will always be ≤ 100 characters.

---

## A Guide to Base85

- Four octets are encoded into (usually) five Base85 characters.
- Base85 characters range from `!` to `u` (ASCII 33 - 117) and `z` (ASCII 122).
- To encode, you continuously perform division by 85 on the four octets (a 32-bit number), and add 33 to the remainder (after each division) to get the ASCII character for the encoded value. For example, the first application of this process produces the rightmost character in the encoded block.
- If a set of four octets contains only null bytes, they are encoded as a `z` instead of `!!!!!`.
- If the last block is shorter than four octets, it's padded with null bytes. After encoding, the same number of characters that were added as padding, are removed from the end of the output.
- The encoded value should be preceded by `<~` and followed by `~>`.
- The encoded value should contain no whitespace (for this challenge).

---

## Examples

```
In: easy
Out: <~ARTY*~>

In: test
Out: <~FCfN8~>

In: code golf
Out: <~@rGmh+D5V/Ac~>

In: Programming Puzzles
Out: <~:i^JeEa`g%Bl7Q+:j%)1Ch7Y~>
```

The following snippet will encode a given input to Base85.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>String.prototype.toAscii85=function(){if(""==this)return"<~~>";for(var r=[],t=0;t<this.length;t+=4){for(var i=(this.substr(t,4)+"\x00\x00\x00").substr(0,4),o=0,n=0;4>n;n++)o=256*o+i.charCodeAt(n);var s=[];for(n=0;5>n;n++){var e=o%85;o=(o-e)/85,s.unshift(String.fromCharCode(e+33))}r=r.concat(s)}var a=4-this.length%4;return 4!=a&&r.splice(-a,a),"<~"+r.join("").replace(/!!!!!/g,"z")+"~>"};</script><style>#in,#out{margin:20px;width:400px;resize:none}</style><input id="in" type="text" value="Base85"><button onclick="$('#out').text($('#in').val().toAscii85())">Submit</button><br><textarea id="out" rows=5 disabled></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why, given that you restrict the input to printable ASCII, you then use *byte* as a synonym of *octet* and don't allow 7-bit bytes.

Comment: Endianness should be specified. A block [0,1,2,3] is converted to a 32 bit number as 0x0123 or 0x3210?

Comment: @edc65 big endian according to the wikipedia link

Comment: @steveverrill thank you. That should be in the challenge text, and not in an external link. At least it's in a comment now

Comment: If the input can only contain printable characters, how could it contain four null bytes?

Comment: I was giving a guide to Base85 in general. Not every point is necessarily applicable to the challenge. @LuisMendo

Comment: Thanks. Like Dennis says, that input can't happen in this case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## CJam, <s>43</s> <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```
"<~"q4/{:N4Ue]256b85b'!f+}/N,)<"~>"
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%3C~%22q4%2F%7B%3AN4Ue%5D256b85b'!f%2B%7D%2FN%2C)%3C%22~%3E%22&input=Programming%20Puzzles).

#### How it works

```
"<~"      e# Push that string.
q4/       e# Read all input from STDIN and split it into chunks of length 4.
{         e# For each chunk:
  :N      e#   Save it in N.
  4Ue]    e#   Right-pad it with 0's to a length of 4.
  256b85b e#   Convert from base 256 to base 85.
  '!f+    e#   Add '!' to each base-85 digit.
}/        e#
N,)       e# Push the length of the last unpadded chunk, plus 1.
<         e# Keep that many chars of the last encoded chunk.
"~>"      e# Push that string.
```

If the input was empty, `N,)` will apply to the string `"<~"`. Since `N` initially holds a single character, the output will be correct.

We don't have to deal with **z** or pad the encoded chunks to length 5, since the input will contain only printable ASCII characters.

Comment: This solution looks suspiciously like the Base85 version of an ASCII string (cf. last example in question). Wait...

Comment: @odjo: There are some invalid characters in the CJam code, the closest I got is [this CJam interpreter link](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%3C~%22q4%2F%7B%3AN4Ue%5D256b85b'!f%2B%7D%2FN%2C%41%3C%22~%3E%22&input=%C3%B9%C2%9D%16%7F%3D%0C%C2%B4h%3F%06Yu%C3%8Av%01r-6*%C2%8D)

Comment: @ojdo because the challenge is just this: `a program that can take an input of a single-line string containing any ASCII printable characters,...`

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 71 bytes

```
from base64 import*
print(a85encode(input().encode(),adobe=1).decode())
```

I've never golfed in Python, so this is probably sub-optimal.

*Thanks to @ZachGates for golfing off 3 bytes!*

Comment: You can use `input().encode()` instead of `str.encode(input())` to save 3 bytes.

Comment: @ZachGates Thanks! All that en-/decoding is still killing me though.

Answer (score 5):

## Pure bash, ~738

Encoder first (something golfed):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ascii 85 encoder bash script
LANG=C

printf -v n \\%o {32..126};printf -v n "$n";printf -v m %-20sE abtnvfr;p=\<~;l()
{ q=$(($1<<24|$2<<16|$3<<8|$4));q="${n:1+(q/64#378iN)%85:1}${n:1+(q/614125)%85:1
}${n:1+(q/7225)%85:1}${n:1+(q/85)%85:1}${n:1+q%85:1}";};k() { ((${#p}>74))&&ech\
o "${p:0:75}" && p=${p:75};};while IFS= read -rd '' -n 1 q;do [ "$q" ]&&{ print\
f -v q "%q" "$q";case ${#q} in 1|2)q=${n%$q*};o+=($((${#q}+32)));;7)q=${q#*\'\\}
o+=($((8#${q%\'})));;5)q=${q#*\'\\};q=${m%${q%\'}*};o+=($((${#q}+07)));;esac;}||
o+=(0);((${#o[@]}>3))&&{ [ "${o[*]}" = "0 0 0 0" ]&& q=z|| l ${o[@]};p+="${q}";k
o=(); };done;[ "$o" ]&&{ f=0;for((;${#o[@]}<4;)){ o+=(0);((f++));};((f==0))&&[ \
"${o[*]}" = "0 0 0 0" ]&&q=z||l ${o[@]};p+="${q:0:5-f}";};p+="~>";k;[ "$p" ]&&e\
cho "$p"
```

Tests:

```
for word in easy test code\ golf Programming\ Puzzles ;do
    printf "    %-24s %s\n" "$word:" $(./enc85.sh < <(printf "$word"))
  done
    easy:                   <~ARTY*~>
    test:                   <~FCfN8~>
    code golf:              <~@rGmh+D5V/Ac~>
    Programming Puzzles:    <~:i^JeEa`g%Bl7Q+:j%)1Ch7Y~>
```

and decoder now:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ascii 85 decoder bash script
LANG=C

printf -v n "\%o" {33..117};printf -v n "$n";o=1 k=1;j(){ read -r q||o=;[ "$q" \
]&&[ -z "${q//*<~*}" ]&&((k))&&k= q="${q#*<~}";m+="$q";m="${m%~>*}";};l(){ r=;f\
or((i=0;i<${#1};i++)){ s="${1:i:1}";case "$s" in "*"|\\|\?)s=\\${s};;esac;s="${\
n%${s}*}";((r+=${#s}*(85**(4-i))));};printf -v p "\%03o" $((r>>24)) $((r>>16&255
)) $((r>>8&255)) $((r&255));};for((;(o+${#m})>0;)){ [ "$m" ] || j;while [ "${m:0
:1}" = "z" ];do m=${m:1};printf "\0\0\0\0";done;if [ ${#m} -ge 5 ];then q="${m:0
:5}";m=${m:5};l "$q";printf "$p";elif ((o));then j;elif [ "${m##z*}" ];then pri\
ntf -v t %$((5-${#m}))s;l "$m${t// /u}";printf "${p:0:16-4*${#t}}";m=;fi;}
```

Copy this in `enc85.sh` and `dec85.sh`, `chmod +x {enc,dec}85.sh`, then:

```
for string in 'ARTY*' 'FCfN8' '@rGmh+D5V/Ac' ':i^JeEa`g%Bl7Q+:j%)1Ch7Y' ;do
    printf "    %-42s %s\n" "<~$string~>:" "$(./dec85.sh <<<"<~$string~>")"
  done
    <~ARTY*~>:                                 easy
    <~FCfN8~>:                                 test
    <~@rGmh+D5V/Ac~>:                          code golf
    <~:i^JeEa`g%Bl7Q+:j%)1Ch7Y~>:              Programming Puzzles

./enc85.sh <<<'Hello world!'
<~87cURD]j7BEbo80$3~>
./dec85.sh <<<'<~87cURD]j7BEbo80$3~>'
Hello world!
```

But you could do some stronger test:

```
ls -ltr --color $HOME/* | gzip | ./enc85.sh | ./dec85.sh | gunzip
```

### Reduced to 724 chars:

```
printf -v n \\%o {32..126};printf -v n "$n";printf -v m %-20sE abtnvfr;p=\<~
l(){ q=$(($1<<24|$2<<16|$3<<8|$4))
q="${n:1+(q/64#378iN)%85:1}${n:1+(q/614125)%85:1}${n:1+(q/7225)%85:1}${n:1+(q/85)%85:1}${n:1+q%85:1}"
};k() { ((${#p}>74))&&echo "${p:0:75}" && p=${p:75};};while IFS= read -rd '' -n 1 q;do [ "$q" ]&&{
printf -v q "%q" "$q";case ${#q} in 1|2)q=${n%$q*};o+=($((${#q}+32)));;7)q=${q#*\'\\}
o+=($((8#${q%\'})));;5)q=${q#*\'\\};q=${m%${q%\'}*};o+=($((${#q}+07)));;esac;}||o+=(0)
((${#o[@]}>3))&&{ [ "${o[*]}" = "0 0 0 0" ]&&q=z||l ${o[@]};p+="${q}";k
o=();};done;[ "$o" ]&&{ f=0;for((;${#o[@]}<4;)){ o+=(0);((f++));}
((f==0))&&[ "${o[*]}" = "0 0 0 0" ]&&q=z||l ${o[@]};p+="${q:0:5-f}";};p+="~>";k;[ "$p" ]&&echo "$p"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <s>193</s> 162 bytes

```
from struct import*
i=raw_input()
k=4-len(i)%4&3
i+='\0'*k
o=''
while i:
 b,=unpack('>I',i[-4:]);i=i[:-4]
 while b:o+=chr(b%85+33);b/=85
print'<~%s~>'%o[k:][::-1]
```

This is my first code golf, so I'm sure there's something wrong with my approach.  I also wanted to actually implement base85 rather than just call the library function.  :)

Comment: This is 181 bytes. Don't forget to remove the newline that IDLE adds to your code when you save (if you're using IDLE). You also never call the function, or get the user's input, so it doesn't do anything when you run it.

Comment: Wasn't sure if it should be a function or read I/O or what... should it read stdin and print stdout?  (Again, never done code golf before...)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! There seems to be a problem with input lengths that are not divisible by 4 (last 2 test cases). Line 3 should read `[:4+len(s)/4*4]` and no characters are removed from the end of the output.

Comment: I believe I've fixed the issues (and unfortunately made it longer).  Trying to optimize more...

Comment: You can turn your second `while` loop into one like like this: `while b:d=chr(b%85+33)+d;b/=85`. You can also remove the space between your `print` statement and the string. Additionally, remove the space between the arguments passed to `s.unpack`.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>133</s> 131 bytes

Thanks to @ojdo for suggesting I take input from argv rather than stdin, saving me 2 bytes.

```
function g(s) p=mod(-numel(s),4);s(end+1:end+p)=0;disp(['<~' dec2base(swapbytes(typecast(s,'uint32')),'!':'u')'(:)'(1:end-p) '~>'])
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
function g(s)             %// function header
p=mod(-numel(s),4);       %// number of missing chars until next multiple of 4
s(end+1:end+p)=0;         %// append p null characters to s
t=typecast(s,'uint32');   %// cast each 4 char block to uint32
u=swapbytes(t);           %// change endian-ness of uint32's
v=dec2base(u,'!':'u');    %// convert to base85
w=v'(:)'(1:end-p);        %// flatten and truncate resulting string
disp(['<~' w '~>']);      %// format and display final result
```

I've posted the code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/dC7lqx). The standalone function doesn't require and `end` statement, but because ideone has the function and the calling script in the same file it requires a separator.

I still haven't been able to figure out how to get `stdin` to work on ideone. If anyone knows, I'm still interested, so please drop me a comment.

Sample output from [ideone](http://ideone.com/dC7lqx):

```
easy
<~ARTY*~>
test
<~FCfN8~>
code golf
<~@rGmh+D5V/Ac~>
Programming Puzzles
<~:i^JeEa`g%Bl7Q+:j%)1Ch7Y~>
```

Comment: Why not just use `argv()`? The task description does not seem to require reading input from `stdin`.

Comment: Very nice! So does `dec2base` in Octave allow bases above 36?

Comment: As the doc (and the error message) say: argument `BASE` must be a number between 2 and 36, *or a string of symbols*. Here, the expression `'i':'u'` expands the the 85 character string ``!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstu`` that serves as the base.

Comment: @ojdo If that's the case then I should make it a function and maybe save a couple of bytes.

Comment: @LuisMendo As ojdo says, `dec2base` will take a base of arbitrary size as long as you give it an alphabet to pull from. For bases `b` less than or equal to 36, it defaults to the first `b` characters of `[0..9,A..Z]`. Any base over 36 requires that you give it the full alphabet (which you can optionally do for smaller bases as well).

Comment: @beaker In Matlab you can't choose the "digits", only the base; and it's limited to 36 maximum :-( That's why I used `bsxfun`

Comment: @LuisMendo Wow, that's interesting. I didn't even look at the Matlab documentation. That kinda stinks.

Comment: @beaker It does. Not only the limitation to 36, but the fact that digits are necessarily 0...9ABC, so there's a jump in ASCII codes

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 175 bytes

```
s=input('','s');m=3-mod(numel(s)-1,4);s=reshape([s zeros(1,m)]',4,[])';t=char(mod(floor(bsxfun(@rdivide,s*256.^[3:-1:0]',85.^[4:-1:0])),85)+33)';t=t(:)';['<~' t(1:end-m) '~>']
```

Example:

```
>> s=input('','s');m=3-mod(numel(s)-1,4);s=reshape([s zeros(1,m)]',4,[])';t=char(mod(floor(bsxfun(@rdivide,s*256.^[3:-1:0]',85.^[4:-1:0])),85)+33)';t=t(:)';['<~' t(1:end-m) '~>']
code golf
ans =
<~@rGmh+D5V/Ac~>
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 181 Bytes

```
foreach(str_split(bin2hex($argn),8)as$v){for($t="",$d=hexdec(str_pad($v,8,0));$d;$d=$d/85^0)$t=chr($d%85+33).$t;$r.=str_replace("!!!!!",z,substr($t,0,1+strlen($v)/2));}echo"<~$r~>";
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c6c334b71a30a8cfdce0390a2181c09b0e98c3b)

Expanded

```
foreach(str_split(bin2hex($argn),8)as$v){
    for($t="",$d=hexdec(str_pad($v,8,0));$d;$d=$d/85^0)
      $t=chr($d%85+33).$t;
    $r.=str_replace("!!!!!",z,substr($t,0,1+strlen($v)/2));
}
echo"<~$r~>";
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 171 bytes

```php
foreach(unpack('N*',str_pad($argn,($m=4-($l=strlen($argn))%4&3)+$l,"\0"))as$c){for($a=$c?'':z;$c|0;$c/=85)$a=chr($c%85+33).$a;$b.=$a;}echo'<~',$m?substr($b,0,-$m):$b,'~>';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BasMwEEX3PoUIk0pq7NjgBEIcx7suSw5QKLIysUNsSUgypWmbo9cd6ObP/PdgxvVuPjSO8mI9Kt2LyTilb4K/PvM0RP/u1FmA8p1JBYz1JhMw1MQHNP9YyuXmqZQrGNLFW7GQUgXQ8ovOka9BN5zv7xXo74Iir3dbSVj3ZPVyt12VpVyDqqBd1zR@UPeWHx48hbEJU0uPBLRpkWYwyj1t/HHk1TyZgJGErBjLc@aRKmsxfiAa5skmzZElM6rwmUQMMdH2jKyzwyU5edt5NY5X07HTdL8PGH6ti1drwpy9/AE)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 314 Bytes

```javascript
a=>(g="<~",h="~>",r=[],t=0,[...a].map((d,h)=>{if(0==h%4){for(n=0,o=0,f=0,s=[],e=0;4>n;)o=256*o+(a.substr(t,4)+"\0\0\0").substr(0,4).charCodeAt(n),n++;for(;5>f;)e=o%85,o=(o-e)/85,s.unshift(String.fromCharCode(e+33)),f++;r=[...r,...s],t+=4}}),d=4-a.length%4,4!=d&&r.splice(-d,d),g+r.join("").replace(/!!!!!/g,"z")+h)
```

This is my first code golf :)

#### Try It‽

```html
<h2>Type Below</h2><input oninput='document.querySelector("p").innerText = (a=>(g="<~",h="~>",r=[],t=0,[...a].map((d,h)=>{if(0==h%4){for(n=0,o=0,f=0,s=[],e=0;4>n;)o=256*o+(a.substr(t,4)+"\0\0\0").substr(0,4).charCodeAt(n),n++;for(;5>f;)e=o%85,o=(o-e)/85,s.unshift(String.fromCharCode(e+33)),f++;r=[...r,...s],t+=4}}),d=4-a.length%4,4!=d&&r.splice(-d,d),g+r.join("").replace(/!!!!!/g,"z")+h))(this.value)'><p>Stuff will go here...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>169</s> <s>165</s> <s>162</s> 160 bytes

```powershell
$ofs=''
"<~$($args-replace'.{1,4}',{$v=$_
&{0..3|%{$n=256*$n+"$v"[$_]}
0..4|%{$r=[char]($n%85+33)+$r;$n-=$n%85;$n/=85}
$r[0..$v.Length]-replace'!!!!!','z'}})~>"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBbT8JAEIXf91eszZSltIAIVVRqQLwkxguKMTEEtZahhZQWdwsqpf3ruBRwnna/c86cZKbhN3Lhoe@vYEgtGq8gHAqLMaI0UsiDzV1R5Dj1bQdZKa4YtYQZMcwteCe5eL9Uqi7VGALrwDwsQKArMFd68N5PiJRqa4lbPcezeT8PgVo39WpV04GfQlC0MiBfZatuJgR4T0ZgXrrFwI28/n/p3nqYwRYsSbT0TFklhDTzxMizOzugzKCskR6Pv8K39Ixpa4y2@N3g1tPza2GHIxTRBl@1h/f1HXbCAVI39IeyopE2@fXE0y/Ml3LL2Tk6PHS5PZmMApd2ZouFjyLznozebvDS/nDVc//oUT8Zq1ql7R29ZjmNLqlKY0LlgIi4DBsU8GeKToQDeWh5v0zjKGZ@JEFO3n/rzJRep9ueiSicPHyOZajfjGl35jgohDQr25xCiw5@ye9us3JKz22BdXNdsd2dkGT1Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>128</s> 114 bytes

```ruby
$_="<~#{$_.gsub(/.{1,4}/){$&.ljust(4,?\0).unpack1("L>").digits(85).reverse.map{(_1+33).chr}.join[..$&.size-5]}}~>"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5LCsIwFAD3PYXEognap8UKLvxcwIV7ldJPGqNtU_IRbKgXceNC8Uy9jULdDzPzeEkT3z575FU5Oj7fRmfeopVuuELLe9-6ITBlYjwB64-DZkKsO4D8bJTGwXhzmBIwZRUlFx-j7RoRSDnjWuHFnICkVyoVhSKqLA790WxGIDnJBs6Cl3uAn0jxmnrzY9Pc16gr_wee7ZBG6uZoqrSTiJT2mMgzZycFk1FR8JL1dqauc6o6_gs)